# Updated Netflix list of TV shows

Tags: json, xml, netflix

is it possible to have an always updated list of TV series on air on `Netflix`?

I'd like to get a public URL that I can access to receive something like a `JSON` o `XML` object with the list?

I don't know much about Netflix so I don't know whether all TV shows are available for all countries at the same moment, but I'm particularly interested in the list of TV shows available for italian users.

Thanks

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Netflix has shut down its public API a year ago: https://gigaom.com/2014/11/14/netflix-is-shutting-down-its-public-api-today/

There's no (legal) way to do this.

Comment: ok I did not know it. So I have to buy the service to get APIs?

Comment: You basically can't unless you are working very closely with Netflix.

Comment: So how do some apps show that a series is on air on Netflix without manually adding this info in their DB?

Comment: Can you show me an app which does this? Probably they are adding it by hand since it does not change that often.

Comment: For example this Android App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.battlelancer.seriesguide. For example the series `Daredevil` says it's on air on Netflix.

Comment: Here's the source code for this app, you might figure it out from that: https://github.com/UweTrottmann/SeriesGuide
I have also found an unofficial API, maybe this helps you: http://netflixroulette.net/api/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Streaming Availability API: https://rapidapi.com/movie-of-the-night-movie-of-the-night-default/api/streaming-availability/

It allows you to query the list of movies and series on Netflix (as well as bunch of other services like Prime Video, Disney+ etc.). It has support for Netflix catalog in Italy too.